# cache webpage in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using c# winform to write a desktop app.

The app needs to show a webpage at startup. However I'm not sure if the Internet is available at each startup so I want to cache the webpage at each run.

Now I'm saving the sourcecode(html only) of the webpage into a file. Yet there could be multiple files related to a webpage, e.g. imgs and css.

Is there an elegant way to cache all these things?

Answer (score 2):

There is no *elegant* way of doing it. For caching you need to download the object (imgs, css & js). Above all caching is a painful thing, many of it has certain expiry time after which it should be re downloaded from server.

You can parse images, css, and Js from html source the easy way using [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) that can help you a lot with parsing the HTML and can make you work little easier.